# Eclipse 3.5 Unable to install plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-3.5

I really don't know what's going on with Eclipse 3.5 (3.5.0 or 3.5.1, same issues), but it's been now 2 days that I'm struggling with Eclipse to find a way to make the plugins installation work via the "Install New Software screen"!!! I have visited a lot of forums and blogs, tried many solutions but in vain: each time the current problem disappears and a new one appears.

I'm trying to make it work at my office, so behind proxy. The best advice I got so far is the one regarding the known issue with NTLM proxies: http://wiki.eclipse.org/ECF_Filetransfer_Support_for_NTLMv2_Proxies. I put in place the hint, but now I have a new error message: Eclipse cannot find the repositories at all... For instance here is what I get now with the Galileo update site itself:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProvisioningUtil.loadMetadataRepository(ProvisioningUtil.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.QueryableMetadataRepositoryManager.doLoadRepository(QueryableMetadataRepositoryManager.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.QueryableRepositoryManager.loadRepository(QueryableRepositoryManager.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.QueryableRepositoryManager.loadAll(QueryableRepositoryManager.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.run(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Samething with http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5, or http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/e3.4/ and whatever the site: no one works.

Please somebody help!

PS: Some more details below:

I have the same issue with third party software too... for instance: http://www.epic-ide.org/updates/testing/site.xml.... same error message.

If I go to Preferences > Install / Updates > Available Software Sites, click on whatever the site and on Test Connection I get a ProvisionException with this error message (when I click on details):

Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/galileo/site.xml.
  Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/galileo/site.xml.
  Server redirected too many  times (20)

**the solution is:**
add following lines to your `eclipse.ini` file (before `-vmargs`):
(verified on 3.5 ; 3.5.1; 3.6.2)

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy
-Dhttp.proxyUser=mydomain\myusername
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

Comment: If it's any consolation, I've got exactly the same problem :(

Comment: I did a new install recently and I found it couldn't connect to the update mirrors. After 3 hard kills via the Task Manager I started Eclipse again and noticed the small popup in the lower-right corner asking me to update Eclipse. Once I updated Eclipse that way, I could connect/download/install the plugin I wanted. I wonder if this might be similar...

Comment: any solution? I have a post a same question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005651/eclipse-helio-update-site-is-not-working.

Comment: It seems the problem with a particular PC. I have two laptop in the same network. One works fine, the other dont. Only difference is one is running XP another one vista.

Comment: I reported a bug for this and they seem to ignore it.  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341845

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had tons of issues here, namely with the proxy support.
We ended-up using Pulse: http://www.poweredbypulse.com/

Pulse has built-in support for a few plugin, however, you can add third-party plugin and even local jar file quite easily.

Strangely it does not always use the built-in Eclipse feature, so sometimes when Eclipse become difficult ( like in our case for the proxy business ), you can work-around it with Pulse.

Comment: Thank you very much for this wonderful advice. Actually Pulse did not really help me directly, but it is by installing it and configuring it that I have fixed my issue: I disabled the SOCKS settings and now it works!! The error message of Pulse was more explicit than the one of Eclipse... Pulse still seems to be a very a good tool! :-)

Comment: To anyone who has some issues with installing plugins in Eclipse 3.5 through Proxy, here are my advices:
- Install the SR1: Eclipse 3.5.1 (they seem to have corrected some stuffs)
- Set the following system property in you eclipse.ini file: -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
For more details on this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/ECF_Filetransfer_Support_for_NTLMv2_Proxies
- Configure only the HTTP and HTTPS proxies. Not SOCKS!!
Normally it should work.
Bye, SirFabel

Answer (score 26):

Use the following setting and you will be all set.
Go to Window --> Preference --> General --> Network Connection --> select Direct from drop down[image]

Comment: This just sorted out a whole host of problems I was having. Thank you, kind sir!

Comment: Thanks a lot, after 3 hr of struggle finally got this. And it is working for me.

Answer (score 8):

Couple of weeks ago I stumbled upon a Problem with Java and a MySQL-Connection. The Problem being that no Connection could be established. Anyway, the fix was to add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to the command line.

I just added the same line to eclipse.ini and as it turns out, it also fixes this issue for me. The option name is pretty self-explainitory: It prefers the IPv4 stack over the IPv6 stack. So this solution may not be viable for everyone.

Comment: Solved it for me running Eclipse Juno (4.2) on the Mac where the other solutions on this page didn't.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem setting up eclipse in the office.
I had set up the for HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS in:

Window>pref>general>network connections

Clearing the proxy settings for SOCKS fixed the problem for me.

Comment: +1 This one did it for me too, no other steps required

Comment: Worked for me on Eclipse Mars !

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem setting up eclipse.

I changed: NATIVE connection to MANUAL and cleared the proxy settings for SOCKS in `Windows` **->** `Preferences` **->** `General` **->** `Network connection`. That fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem. I changed **Direct** connection to **Native** and it worked.

Preferences → General →  Network Connections.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read this post?

http://eclipsewebmaster.blogspot.ch/search?q=wow-what-a-painful-release-this-was-is

Maybe it explains, why it was kinda difficult the last days.

Comment: The post doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I had to turn off my personal firewall and Windows firewall as well, and it worked in the end.

Answer (score 0):

i fought with eclipse 3.5.0 (galileo) for days, i had to use this version because I am doing blackberry development and eclipse comes bundle with blackberry specifics so i need to use
the package they bundled, which was not 3.5.0 (not the 3.5.1) , BUT
SirFabel  saved the day, thanks to all who contributed to this post

I used 3.5.0 and did 
"Set the following system property in you eclipse.ini file: -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient For more details on this: wiki.eclipse.org/… - Configure only the HTTP and HTTPS proxies. Not SOCKS!!  "

and I am able to get through my companies proxy!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this as I have had problems with an install of eclipse on my machine.

Specs: Win 7 x64 on macbook pro. The broken eclipse was galileo, and 1 of 4 installations on my machine at the time - the others were all working.

I was not running proxy, so above solution in the question did not work.

I found an answer that said to get updates for eclipse, and that would fix things. I tried this, and eclipse said there were no updates, but then for some reason I can't understand, my plugins could now install.

... more anecdotal evidence of a problem, and a possible solution, however strange ...

Answer (score 0):

Its the Windows OS that make the problem. I got the same problem. Then I tried some other app which use JavaVM to connect the internet, and they fails. Try update JRE, you will notice it. If JRE cannot update itself, then there is some socket inaccessibility that prevent internet access apart from using native windows API.
I reinstall Win7 and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

finally I got eclipse 3.7 working behind company firewall. I set to true "java.net.useSystemProxies" option on file "net.properties" located on "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib" (this path could be different for your JRE installation). After that,set Active provider to Native on Eclipse preferences. No need to provide any proxy details anywhere, it just pick it up  from system default browser settings

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same questions in 3.7 on ubuntu 12.04.
My Os use a proxy 127.0.0.1,and the eclipse use another proxy 192.168.1.1.

I read the .log for info. It says 
!MESSAGE System property http.proxyHost is set to 127.0.0.1 but should be 192.168.1.1.

so I change the eclipse net work setting to the same as the system .
At last,it works.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem while working with eclips Neon. It got fixed after editing the .ini file with following content:

```
>    -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080

>    -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy

>    -Dhttp.proxyUser=mydomain\myusername

>    -Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword

>    -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1

>    -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Note: Sometime it may also caused due to the issue with your Network configuration and device. So conform first that your windows firewall is allowing to connect your eclips to the outer world (internet). (Turn off the windows firewall for the instance of time that your computer take to install the file).

Answer (score 0):

In my eclipse Luna  faced the same issue because of this URL **https://sourceforge.net/projects/restfulplugin/files/site/**

So i just Disabled  the URL that was Shown in the Error From the Available Software Sites.

You may Check the URL or Try with the Updated URL reg to that Exception :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error while trying to connect for updates.
Just did as in the above answer -

**Window**-> **Preferences**-> **General**-> **Network**

There the default provider was set as Native. I changed it to **direct** as my laptop didn't need to connect to any proxy.

Applied and it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need of doing such hectic stuffs. Find in your system where there is "SDK Manager".(incase of windows). Suppose your sdk manager is in E:\Android-9. Go to that path double click the SDK manager ;it will automatically start to download from 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/../..

Initially you will se it is failing. On the window that appears there will be 'settings' menu. Click on that set the proxy and port. and it will start downloading.

The solution in one sentence is "Don't use eclipse for the download;directly use Android sdk manager and your problem is resolved". Let me know if you have any futhur queries on this issue.

Comment: Android is..never mentioned whatsoever in the questions, nor comments.

Comment: The TE never mentioned android.