# help:update adt appear mistake:org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException

Tags: android

my eclipse is 3.6,i have installed the  latest sdk,but when i install   the ADT 10.0 ,it appear mistake:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException
```

nable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found this question is repeated link: [Eclipse 3.5 Unable to install plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500646/eclipse-3-5-unable-to-install-plugins) ,through it is 3.5 eclipse,my eclipse is 3.6,but the question is same ,and solved also same.