# How do I configure proxy settings in eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse

I need a windows builder tool in eclipse, so i tried to install a new software which is located in help option.

**But I get this error :**

> HTTP Proxy Authentication Required:
>   ://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201506241200-1/4.5/ 
>   content.xml HTTP Proxy Authentication Required:
>   hp://download.eclipse.org/window builder/W B/release/ R 2
>   01506241200-1/4.5/co n t e n t.x m  l Proxy Authentication Required
>   org.eclipse .equinox.p 2.core. Prov is ion E c e p t ion

Comment: I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500646/eclipse-3-5-unable-to-install-plugins) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can set proxy inside eclipse by going to 
Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections